# A flow trigger failed to execute with Version ID -

Tags: flow, process-builder, process, null

I have one Process builder 
which calls Flow
which call another flow.

I came across following two situations on Case -

ERROR Message 1:

> **Workflow Action failed to Trigger Flow**
>
> The record couldn't be saved because if failed to trigger a flow. A
>   flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID #######Flow
>   id#####. Contact your administrator for help.

ERROR Message 2:

> A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID #### Flow id ###.

** I get that its happening because of some  Flow ->Version.

But What could be the possible wrong situations here ? 
Please explain. What could go wrong ?

(like-
1- Flow is not getting invoked.

2- Flow Version is not invoked all.

3- Flow Version has some issues in its -Conditions/xyz/etc.
)

and What I should be looking at ? What I should be my steps to check this?

---

---

**Question 2 : Related to this**

So, After investigation I found out that my Case record was not having "Account" lookup value populated in it.

AND

in process builder I am assigning 
var parentid = Case.AccountID   --- into one variable,

which variable 'parentid' is then used in Flow.

So, How can I stop facing this error in a situation where my Case doesn't have Account populated on it?

**Something like this ---**

```
  if(Case.AccountID != null){
           ///*****then avoid using this and go for next step in Process Builder's 
    }

    OR -in Flow 
    if(ParentID != null){
           ///***** then avoid this using this and go for next step in Flow.
    }
```

**1) Should I check this Process Builder or in Flow ?**

**2) If yes, then how to do it in Process builder OR in Flow ?**

Comment: What exactly is your Flow doing?  I would specifically look to see if there are any 'time-based' workflows that might be somehow related to the execution of your Flow.

Comment: I've had this message on a couple of occasions and I have been unable to fix the flow itself. I think that the way to fix it is to raise a ticket with Salesforce support

Comment: @DavidLitton  - There are no any 'time-based' workflows. My flows are just getting count of records (collection) which are child of Account on my Case. and at one point it pause/resume another flow, which shows/updates collections.

Comment: @mkorman  - Thank you for your inputs. I also thinking the same way, because my flows doesn't have any flaws in it. STILL - Can you point at some proof/document/answer/blog/anything - which I can use to explain this, and then proceed with Support Ticket ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will help but maybe can try.For my case, I notice the sequence of condition will impact the process builder.For example :

The condition below can cause an exception if the Contact inserted without Account because at the condition 2, it tries to search for Account.Myfield__c while AccountId not even exist.

> 1.Contact.Myfield__c is null
>   2.Contact.Account.Myfield__c is not null
>   3.Contact.AccountId is not null

This is the correct sequence because it checks AccountId first because it checks Account.My_field__c .So this will not cause the exception.

> 1.Contact.Myfield__c is null
>   2.Contact.AccountId is not null
>   3.Contact.Account.Myfield__c is not null

For more info please refer to this :`

[http://shelovestocode.blogspot.my/2016/07/process-builder-exception-record.html](http://shelovestocode.blogspot.my/2016/07/process-builder-exception-record.html/)

`